# Differences GCM Accessing APIs directly from Android and Accessing APIs via a web server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to know the differences between creating GCM API Key by `Accessing APIs directly from Android` and by `Accessing APIs via a web server`. I'd like to know the advantages and disadvantages of both.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The APIs for server and client have different purposes. From the server to access GCM via HTTP or XMPP protocol to send messages to your app on Android devices. In the client (Android app) you have APIs (via the GoogleCloudMessaging class) to register your app to GCM and send upstream messages from your app to your server.

Comment: @Eran - I don't think you need the API key in your Android app to register for GCM. My app, with the new non-deprecated interface, is registered and has no reference to my "AIz........." API key. That key exists only in the web pages of my app server.

Comment: @NickT I never mentioned the API key in my comment. You are correct - API key is not required for registration.

Comment: @Eran, yes you are right, sorry for any confusion, I don't remember having to provide the SHA fingerprint to get my API key, is that a relatively new requirement?

Comment: on console -> Register new application. There are two options for android: 
Accessing APIs directly from Android
Accessing APIs via a web server

The first option requires Package name and SHA1 fingerprint the second option does not require. when the first or second option is used?

Comment: @NickT Yes, that's a new requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what you were asking. According to the [GCM Docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html), in order to obtain an API Key, you should choose `Accessing APIs directly from Android`.

> To obtain an API key:
>
> ```
> 1. In the sidebar on the left, select APIs & auth > Registered apps.
> 2. Click Register app.
> 3. In the Name field, type your app's name.
> 4. Click Android > Accessing APIs directly from Android.
> 5. Under Android identification, type the package name for your app.
> 6. Enter an SHA1 fingerprint. To get this value, follow the instructions in the console help.
> 7. Click Register.
> ```

As to what's the difference in general between `Accessing APIs directly from Android` and `Accessing APIs via a web server`, I assume that in the latter case, the Android device doesn't access the Google API directly. Instead, your web server communicates with the API and delivers to the Android app the relevant data. In GCM, the Android device must communicate with the API directly, in order to register the device to GCM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the differences in the two types of connections allowed for GCM (namely HTTP & XMPP/CCS)? The differences can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#choose).

In short...

- HTTP can only *push* messages downstream to devices, whereas XMPP/CCS
  is bidirectional.
- HTTP is synchronous whereas XMPP/CCS is asynchronous.

A caveat of using XMPP/CCS (that isn't very well documented IMO) is that you must sign up to use GCM with XMPP [here](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/) and hopefully be approved/accepted where with HTTP, you can just simply use it.